# How do I write a unit test code for this piece of code

Tags: python, unit-testing

Below is my code which replaces some characters in string based on the key available in the dictionary:

```
import re

D = {'h':'hhh', 'l':'nnn'}
enpattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?', re.IGNORECASE)

def convert(str):
    result = [x.group() for x in enpattern.finditer(str)]
    data = ''.join(map(lambda x:D.get(x.lower(), x.lower()), result))
    print data
```

How do i write a unit test for this code such that the arguments to convert() is never a integer and it should accept only strings or special characters like `'$'`.

How to write a unit test such that I can check for `char`, `int` or any other data types that can be passed as an argument generally.

Answer (score 0):

Unit-testing without special tools:

```
print convert("somestring") == "expected_result_for_somestring"
print convert("otherstring") == "expected_result_for_otherstring"
print convert("stringWith$") == "expected_result_for_stringWith$"
```

Or maybe you need no "unit test" but "test of arguments passed to convert()"

```
def convert(param):
    if type(param) == int:
        print "wrong argument type: int"
        return 
    if type(param) == str and "$" in param:
        print "wrong char in string: $"
        return
```

BTW: don't use `str` as variable name.

---

**EDIT:** primitive testing with `list` and `for`

```
def convertTest():

    datas = (
        ( "somestring",  "expected_result_for_somestring"), 
        ( "otherstring", "expected_result_for_otherstring"), 
        ( "stringWith$", "expected_result_for_stringWith$")
    )

    for input, output in datas:
        print input, "result:", convert(input) == output
```

---

**EDIT:** example of primitive testing of 3 functions (three different authors) to convert Roman numbers to Arabic numbers on "Polish Python Coders Group" forum:

Look for `testowe` (testing datas) and `test()`

http://pl.python.org/forum/index.php?topic=4399.msg18831#msg18831

Comment: Could you please explain the first part of your answer , how does it works, Should I keep those 3 print statement in file and run it. Is using Assert possible here? I am learning to use NOSE testing , so I am looking for something which works on nosetest!

Comment: I create new function (for example `convertTest()`) with this 3 prints in new file or in file with `convert()` and run it every time I change something in `convert()`. It is simillar to `asert` but it doesn't raise error and always print result `True` or `False`. It is not so powerfull like real unit test but sometimes it is easer to create - and it is better to have primitive test than to have nothing. ps. some times I use list with '(input,output)' and `for` to make tests event easer - see example in my answer.